# How to test iOS web application using Instruments UIAutomation

Tags: ios, web-applications, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

When I test native application I can choose target (application from real device listed in the choose target list; or in the case with simulator - choose Profile menu item in application project).

**But how can I choose target for web application?**

Do I have to choose some browser as a target in this case? Device has Safari and Chrome browsers. Chrome browser appears in the list of targets. But when I try to run script, it does not works. Chrome is just launched, but any actions are performed.

I have also tried to create XCode project that simply open web page in browser. But when I try to run the script error "target application is not the frontmost" appears.
Is there some possibility to choose applications installed on the device as a target, if they are not present in the Instruments choose target list? There is a link to the web application on device home page. Can I somehow choose it as a target? In Organizer (called from XCode) only one - native - application is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

UI Automation will only work for native applications built by you with Xcode. From your question it sounds like you want to launch Mobile Safari or Chrome for iOS and manipulate that with UI Automation. That won't work. Instruments can let you connect to applications you didn't compile running on the simulator or device, but only some of the instruments work and UI Automation isn't one of them.

If your web app was wrapped in a native shell then you could use UI Automation. You might want to look into [Phone Gap](http://phonegap.com). It's a full fledged wrapper that tries to expose native functionality to web apps, which you wouldn't need. But the fact that it's a well supported wrapper around web pages could be a great place to start if you still wanted to try this.

Answer (score 1):

UI Automation doesn't support web automation. Try Selenium web driver for iOS, helps to automate web apps on iOS Safari browser. runs on both device and on simulator.